# What will happen to block if more than one transaction are changing same asset in same block in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am bit confused to understand following use case:

Lets assume, We have more than one transactions in same block which are changing state of same asset, then what will happen in consensus cycle of Hyperledger Fabric?

- Block will be rejected
- First transaction in block will be successful, but rest of them will be failed

Kindly help me to understand this corner case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consensus in Fabric involves multiple pieces:

1. Invoking chaincode functions and obtaining enough endorsements
   (typically signatures) to meet the endorsement policy by invoking
   the chaincode and receiving responses from the correct number of
   peers
2. Submitting the transactions to the ordering service node(s) which reach consensus on the order of transactions and then package them into blocks
3. Ordering node(s) broadcast the transactions to the peer nodes which then validate the transactions and commit state changes for valid transactions

Peers validate transactions by checking to make sure each transaction meets the endorsement policy for the chaincode invoked and then checks the *read set* of each transaction to make sure that the version of each key which was read in the chaincode has not changed.  If it has changed, the transaction is marked invalid and it's write set (state changes) is not processed.  The transaction still remains in the block but the block is annotated with metadata indicating the status of each transaction in the block.  The validation and commit logic is deterministic.

You should read through the [Transaction Flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/txflow.html) and [Read-Write set semantics](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/readwrite.html#) in the documentation for the lower level details.

Comment: Got it, Thank You Gari Singh.